# ArgumentError SMTP To address may not be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm getting ArgumentError SMTP "To address" may not be blank from the Mailer that I created for the test.

My code is almost same with an example in the Rails Guide that you can find in here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Or Ruby on Rails tutorial:
https://3rd-edition.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#sec-account_activation_mailer

## Server log

```
Error performing ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: fa1eac9b-a2e0-4b4b-aca7-c785141fd7ce) from Async(mailers) in 214.6ms: ArgumentError (SMTP To address may not be blank: []):
```

## My Code

```
  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'sendish.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

# app/mailers/appliction_mailer.rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end

# app/mailer/user_mailer.rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    attachments.inline['helloworld.gif'] = File.read(Rails.root + 'public/helloworld.gif')
    mail to: user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site'
  end
end

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save
        UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now

        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :login)
    end
```

I see Mailer is passing To address in my development

```
UserMailer#welcome_email: processed outbound mail in 26.0ms
Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2020 15:01:52 -0700
From: notifications@example.com
To: user@example.com
Subject: Welcome to My Awesome Site
```

## Addtional Information

The issue is happening in Heroku production

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in the failing method and walk up the stack inspecting variables until you identify where the empty to is coming from.

Comment: Is it possible that `user.email` is `nil` for your production (Heroku) user?

Comment: Do you know how to put a breakpoint for debugging in Heroku?